# Problem on making a multi-finder dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dictionary

I'm trying to make a web page that searches a word in English or Spanish.
To do this, I use 2 tabs, one in English, and one in Spanish. Each tab has an associated div, so if I click on the English tab it will take me to the English div and if I click on the spanish tab will take me to the spanish div.
Within each of these divs there is a search bar with the "Search" button and 8 more tabs with their corresponding associated divs.
Each div of these has an iframe which is where I want the search result to come up.

The idea is the following:

1. Click on the English tab.
2. I write 'water', for example, and press the "Search" button.
3. If I click on any of the 8 tabs below, the body of the page as a result of the search must be displayed, inside the iframe.

The problem is that the destination pages are not shown inside the iframe, it tells me that it has to be a complete page.
Can this be solved in any way?

This is my code I have at the moment only implemented rae spanish dictionary
but the error is the same on

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicenes</title>
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript" src="fJavascript.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.tabs.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.tabs.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabIdiomas">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Inglés</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Español</a></li>
</ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <label for="txtIngles">Búsqueda:</label>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="txtIngles" id="txtIngles" style="width: 150 px;">
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" name="cmdBuscarIngles" id="cmdBuscarIngles" value="Buscar">
    <p></p>
<div id="tabIngles">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Ficha 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ficha 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Ficha 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-6">Ficha 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-7">Ficha 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-8">Ficha 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-9">Ficha 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-10">Ficha 8</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Contenido 1 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>Contenido 2 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-5">
        <p>Contenido 3 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-6">
        <p>Contenido 4 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-7">
        <p>Contenido 5 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-8">
        <p>Contenido 6 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-9">
        <p>Contenido 7 inglés</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-10">
        <p>Contenido 8 inglés</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <label for="txtEspañol">Búsqueda:</label>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="txtEspañol" id="txtEspañol" style="width: 150 px;">
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" name="cmdBuscarEspañol" id="cmdBuscarEspañol" value="Buscar" onClick="buscar(txtEspañol.value, 'español')">
    <p></p>
    <div id="Tabs1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-11">Collins</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-12">Ficha 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-13">Ficha 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-14">Ficha 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-15">Ficha 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-16">Ficha 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-17">RAE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-18">DIRAE</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-11">
        <p>Contenido 1 español</p>
        <iframe name="fraE1" id="fraE1" width=883></iframe>

      </div>
      <div id="tabs-12">
        <p>Contenido 2 español</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-13">
        <p>Contenido 3 español</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-14">
        <p>Contenido 4 español</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-15">
        <p>Contenido 5 español</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-16">
        <p>Contenido 6 español</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-17">
        <p>Contenido 7 español</p>
        <iframe name="fraE7" id="fraE7"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-18">
        <p>Contenido 8 español</p>
        <iframe name="fraE8" id="fraE8" width=883></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $( "#tabIdiomas" ).tabs(); 
});
$(function() {
  $( "#tabIngles" ).tabs(); 
});
$(function() {
  $( "#Tabs1" ).tabs(); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the javascript file

```
    function buscar(termino, idioma)
    {
        if(termino == "")
        {
            alert("Campo 'Búsqueda' en blanco");
            return false;
        }
        switch(idioma)
        {
            case "ingles":
            break;
            case "español":
                document.getElementById("fraE1").src = "https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/espanol-ingles/" + termino;
                document.getElementById("fraE7").src = "https://dle.rae.es/" + termino;
                document.getElementById("fraE8").src = "https://dirae.es/palabras/" + termino;
                
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to solve `it tells me that it has to be a complete page`

Comment: I think is is by https. Is there any way to call an https page and return it like http?

Comment: ¡Done! I have to change all the code to VB.NET, but it works. Thanks for all.